# Two UITableView one Loads Fine Other Does Not

Tags: objective-c

I have two uitableview elements on my view controller ...  the tableview for person loads fine shows the persons name in the table and when i select a person i get the personID in my NSLog and personName populates the UILabel just fine BUT the tableview for team loads *NSCFString and when i select it the app crashes and this is in the log: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[*_NSCFString teamID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance......"

.m

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{


    if (tableView == _personList){
        return [personData count];
    }else{
        return [teamData count];
    }


}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (tableView == _personList){

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Persons *person = [personData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = person.personName;

    return cell;
    }else {

        if(!cell){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        Teams *team = [teamData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = team.teamName;
        return cell;

    }
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 if (tableView == _personList){

    Persons *person = [personData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString *selPersonID = person.personID;
     _thePersonName.text = person.personName;
     NSLog(@"PersonID: %@", selPersonID);

 }else if(tableView == _teamList){

     Teams *team = [teamData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSString *selTeamID = team.teamID;
     _theTeamName.text = team.teamName;
     NSLog(@"TeamID: %@", selTeamID);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that the object that tries to get its teamID, doesn't have a teamID property (because your array somehow returns an NSString, not a Team object).

So you have to see if your teamData array is filled correctly with Team objects.

Comment: oh dear... time to step away from the computer!... that was it! thank you!